# Issue rendering Basic HTML (without inline CSS styles) using Flying Saucer ITextRenderer

Tags: java, pdf, jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am very new to Flying Saucer.
I am generating PDFs using ITextRenderer class in Java.
The problem that I am facng is, the HTML that i need to convert, contains basic HTML tags WITHOUT INLINE CSS STYLES.
For Example:-

```
<p><b>hello</b> <i>this</i> is a <u>sample</u>
<font color="#FF6600">text for HTML</font> to pdf <font size="18">gen</font></p>
```

What I notice is that, in the above HTML, the attributes of font tag (size, color etc) have no effect in the PDF. Whereas, I have also been experimenting by hardcoding an HTML with inline CSS styles which works perfectly fine.
But my problem is I want the above HTML attributes to work due to several reasons...

Any helpful pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mangirish

Answer (score 0):

Flying saucer doesn't support attributes on the `<font>` tag -- you need to use inline styles, like `<font style="...">`.

Comment: Hi Matt, I would rather say that flying saucer doesn't support font tags with attributes... because the font tag with inline styles work fine..

Comment: @Mangirish -- okay, incorporated that info into my answer.